# ImageMagick: Is it possible to remove "Crop marks"?

Tags: bash, pdf, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to create a a thumb of a PDF.

```
/opt/local/bin/convert \
   "$inputFile[0]"     \
  -geometry 157x200    \
  -colorspace RGB      \
   "$ThumbFile"
```

But lastly we got PDF with "crop marks" (for bleeding).

Is there an option that I can use to don't take those?

How can I do this?

**Example:**

[image]

I would like to have only the content of the second image.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your crop-marked PDF? Then I can give you a command that removes or disables the crop-marks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended by indicating to image magick to grab only the trim box:

```
/opt/local/bin/convert \
  -geometry 157x200    \
  -colorspace RGB      \
  -define pdf:use-trimbox=true \
   "$inputFile[0]"     \   
   "$ThumbFile"
```

Answer (score 1):

The very simple to use `-shave N` parameter will remove N pixels depth from each edge of the image.

For example:

```
convert         \
   original.gif \
  -shave 30     \
   result.gif
```

This will shave of the 30 outmost rows/columns of pixels from each edge of the original image.

This also works for PDF input pages (and PNG output thumbnails, for example):

```
convert        \
   some.pdf[0] \
  -scale 25%   \
  -shave 30    \
   result.png
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it this way, the margin will never be thé same. And if I print this PDF in Adobe, I can just say that it shouldnt print crop marks. It's à real functionality of PDF, and not just margins

Comment: @J4N: Can you provide a sample of your crop-marked PDF? Then I can give you a command that removes or disables the crop-marks...

Comment: I'm sorry, I found the solution, but it was the release week, so I didn't think of putting the answer here. I will post the code ASAP